# IE8 giving very wierd error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

This is the error I am receiving,

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Mon, 9 May 2016 09:54:15 UTC
Message: 'key' is null or not an object
Line: 2031
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: https://www.example.com/Scripts/odata-query-builder.js
```

This is the JS file from Microsoft I am using,

https://odatasamples.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Tools/ODataQueryBuilder/Scripts/odata-query-builder.js

Line: 2031 looks like this to me,

```
$.each(options, function (index, e) {
Line 2031:        var $option = $('<option />', { value: e.key, text: e.value });

    if (typeof e.type !== 'undefined' && e.type == 'navigationProperty') {
        $option.addClass('navigationDropdown');
    }

    $option.appendTo(select);
});
```

**Update**

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 as 2.0.0 is not supported by IE8

**Update 2**

To make things move forward I added this bit to Options,

```
if(e){ rest of code here... }
```

but now I am getting another error on line 477, Char 9

```
  OData.read({ requestUri: this.getODataUrl() + '$metadata' },
```

Comment: can you debug it and see what happens? Maybe e.key is actually not an object...

Comment: which version of jquery? Maybe i's a jquery 2+ issue? https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @RegisPortalez—IE 8 still has around 6% user share (per [*NetMarketShare*](https://www.netmarketshare.com/)), which is about the same as IE 10.

Comment: not sure why OData is not having all the methods it requires